# how to block false user name and email in commits

Tags: git

i want to block those commits in the server which has false user name and email.
The authentication is via ssh. It is currently posible for me to update the config user.name and user.email to something other than mine and still commit and push to central repo. The history now shows wrong information about committer.
Any ideas, how we can prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to associated the ssh key with an email and deny commits that have a different email.

Comment: Any hints/links on how to do this? My google-fu has failed me

Comment: Yes, me too. Would appreciate if you can advise how this can be done. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Emails and usernames can be spoofed.

The best way would be to sign the commits with a gpg key.

https://phreaknerd.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/signing-git-commits-with-your-gpg-key/

```
gpg --list-keys  
git config --global user.signingkey 123ABC89  
git commit -S
```

Comment: The gpg key may change after years. If it changed later, does that mean older history become invalid data?